# ECMA Script feature support table for modern browsers WANTED

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

Almost everone has seen the [quirksmode](http://quirksmode.org) browser support tables for CSS (and some other features). They look awesome.

I am looking for ECMA Script table, not [Dom Features](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html) or [JS API](http://caniuse.com/#cats=JS_API). Does IE9 support `Array.indexof()`? `Array.map()`? GreaseMonkey vs V8?

I have found [this](http://pointedears.de/scripts/test/es-matrix/), but I consiter it **unreadable**: (

Comment: Does it need to be a table? I find https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference very useful, though you have to drill down for each feature separately.

Comment: It should be a fast-readable browser-support table

Comment: possible duplicate of [List of areas missing support for ECMAScript/JavaScript in major browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103833/list-of-areas-missing-support-for-ecmascript-javascript-in-major-browsers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [es5 compatibility table](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/) maybe gives some help